# Bad horizontal spacing when using the fourier/utopia font

Tags: spacing, letterspacing, fourier

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}

If \(0<b<1\).

\emph{If \(0<b<1\)}.

\emph{If 0<b<1}

\end{document}
```

that yields the following output:

[image]

As far as I can tell, the horizontal spacing between the `f` and `0` in the second case is not optimal. Is it a feature, bug or misuse on my side?

### Edit:

In case it is a "feature" (as @Mico suggests), how can I solve it globally? I have something like `If \(0<b<1\)` *inside* theorem-environment, thus the italic and I am looking for a way out that won't involve manual fix.

Comment: I might diagnose the problems exhibited by the second case as follows: LaTeX is in (text-)italic mode, but it doesn't know that it should be inserting an italic correction after "If" because it doesn't "know" that the first item inside the math mode part (`0`) is set in an upright font. I'm not sure I'd call it a bug; really more of a feature. If you really need to typeset the second case, you should provide an explicit italic correction, viz., write `\emph{If\/ \(0<b<1\)}.`

Comment: It seems like you're right. If I remove the `fourier` package, then a similar issue arises, only it is not as visible as when `utopia` is in use.

Comment: Or, `\emph{If} $0<b<1$`, which should insert the italic correction automatically.

Comment: See my edit, the problem is that I have this issue inside an environment.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. AFAIK, there's no (reasonably easy) way to make it work automagically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `mathtools` package provides the option `mathic=true` for inserting such italic corrections automatically:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier,mathtools}

\begin{document}

If \(0<b<1\).

\emph{If \(0<b<1\)}.

\emph{If 0<b<1}.

\mathtoolsset{mathic=true}
\emph{If \(0<b<1\)}.

\emph{If 0<b<1}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it safe/advisable to turn this `mathic` on globally?

Comment: @Dror I use it globally in my documents.  Recent updates to `mathtools` means that these operations are robust, so this may be used in captions and index entries.  Note that you have to use `\(...\)` rather than `$...$` for the maths.

Comment: Does "Globally" mean that you have the line `mathtoolsset{mathic=true}` right after the `\begin{document}` or in the preamble?

Comment: @Dror in the preamble.